# To have a road hung

Tags: vocabulary

What does "hung" mean in this text? At first I thought that it might mean that the road to the dump was floating above ground, but I don't think that's the case. Then I thought it might mean "outlined" which would make more sense, but I was unable to find that meaning for the word "hung" in any dictionary. Any help is appreciated.

Source: Roadside Picnic book.

> Forty yards. Where was he counting from? Oh, probably from the last
> pylon. He's right, it wouldn't be further than that from there. Those
> egghead scientists were making progress. They've got **the road hung** all
> the way to the dump, and cleverly hung at that!

Comment: Do you mean [this book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roadside_Picnic)? If so, it's a translation from the Russian. Could it be something about power lines hanging from the pylons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, "hung" means "decorated". The scientists had decorated the road nicely all the way to the dump.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hang) has this definition:

> **hang**
> *transitive verb*
> **2 :** to furnish with hanging decorations (such as flags or bunting)
> *// **Hang** the windows with velvet curtains.
>
> // a room **hung** with streamers*

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!

Comment: Is there some context that I'm missing?  The source doesn't mention any kind of decorations. Decorating roads would not normally be a task for "egghead scientists"